# Angular ngFor cannot display data <!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]" }-->

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular, I have read many discussions about my problem without finding a solution. My front is generating a  for my ngFor.

I can see in the console that I obtain the data from my API. Someone can helps me?

Here is my component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { BasicRequestsService } from '../services/basic-requests.service';
import { Observable, concat } from 'rxjs';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})


export class HomeComponent {
    env = environment;
    usersList;

  constructor(
    private basicRequestsService: BasicRequestsService,

    ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    const args = new Array();

    concat(
      this.getUsersData(),


      )
    .subscribe();

  }

  getUsersData(): Observable<any>  {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.basicRequestsService.get('/users')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.usersList = data;
        console.log(this.usersList);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <th>Client</th>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let userList of usersList">
          <td>{{ userList.firstName }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am loading the data from my API.

[image]

Comment: Please share console.log(data.data)

Comment: try this.usersList = data.data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From console.log it clearly seems that you are getting object with status,message and data and you need to take data from that object
So use "data.data" to get usersList

```
getUsersData(): Observable<any>  {
return Observable.create(observer => {
  this.basicRequestsService.get('/users')
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.usersList = data.data;
    console.log(this.usersList);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>Client</th>       
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let userList of usersList">
       <td>{{ userList?.firstName }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sajeethan !

It has just changed my binding to 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and after searching a lot, I found out that I used a method inside `ngFor` that did not exist in `.ts` file!